# Why does Kotlin's compiler not realize when a variable is initialized in an if statement?

Tags: kotlin, compiler-errors

The following example of Kotlin source code returns an error when compiled:

```
fun main() {

  var index: Int // create an integer used to call an index of an array
  val myArray = Array(5) {i -> i + 1} // create an array to call from

  val condition = true // makes an if statement run true later

  if (condition) {
    index = 2 // sets index to 2
  }
    
  println( myArray[index] ) // should print 2; errors
  
}
```

The error says that the example did not initialize the variable `index` by the time it is called, even though it is guaranteed to initialize within the `if` statement. I understand that this problem is easily solved by initializing `index` to anything before the `if` statement, but why does the compiler not initialize it? I also understand that Kotlin is still in beta; is this a bug, or is it intentional? Finally, I am using [Replit](https://replit.com/) as an online IDE; is there a chance that the compiler on the website simply is an outdated compiler?

Comment: TL;DR: path analysis/execution during compilation isn't exhaustive, which means obvious *(-to-us)* runtime values aren't always detected at compile time.

Comment: The compiler doesn’t evaluate every possible code path to determine this kind of thing, only some short, more obvious things that don’t require stepping back to look at the bigger picture.

Comment: Checking _every_ possible combination throughout the code would be equivalent to solving the Halting Problem, which is impossible in general. So the compiler has to draw the line somewhere! In practice, it makes on fairly basic checks, because that keeps the compile time down. And if the compiler has trouble telling whether a variable is always initialised, then anyone reading the code is likely to find it hard too — so keeping the checks simple is one way to encourage people to write clear, simple code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler checks whether there is a path in your code that the index may not be initialized based on all the path available in your code apart from the value of the parameters. You have an if statement without any else. If you add the else statement you will not get any compile error.